# JavaScript regex is not working in Java

Tags: java, javascript, regex

```
"^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{5})|((\+44\s?\d{5}|\(?0\d{5}\)?)\s?\d{5})|((\+44\s?\d{5}|\(?0\d{5}\)?)\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$";
```

I use the above pattern to validate UK telephone number. It's working in JavaScript (client side). but its not working in Java code (server side).
The error message says `invalid escape sequence`.

Comment: I'm going to deploy a favourite quote here - "You think that you need a regex to solve your problem, so you write one. Now you have 2 problems." The point being that perhaps when regexes get this big and ugly, it's time to look at solving your problem another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to replace all your `\` with `\\`
Having said that, it seems like your regex is a bit complicated for a phone-number?
I see that the country-code for GB (+44) is included quite a few times, so I guess you could be able to say that only once:

```
^(\+44)?(...)
```

And the rest of the regex where the elipsis are.

Another idea to make this clearer is to break this regex into several ones for each case like:

```
if (matches case 1) return true; // example of case one
if (matches case 2) return true; // example of case two
if (matches case 3) return true; // example of case tree
...
return false;
```

In my opinion this code would be much simpler to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

That's because Java simply doesn't accept `\` in a string (since `\` is unescaped). Escape `\` with `\\` instead.